# Deletion of 3 year old files using sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete the files which are having 3 year old files from a folder. But when I am running the code it is also deleting the other files which are not in the file name frmat which I tried to delete. The file name is like **SFRE_BIL_SIT_20160812_134317_PAM_FILES1.zip** I attached the code also with this

```
options mlogic;
%macro delete_year_files_in_folder(folder);
   filename filelist "&folder";
   data _null_;
      dir_id = dopen('filelist');
      total_members = dnum(dir_id);
      do i = 1 to total_members; 
       member_name = dread(dir_id,i);
    datestring = scan(member_name,4,'_');       
    month = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.);
    day = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.);
    year = input(substr(datestring,1,4),best.);
    date = mdy(month, day, year);
         if intnx('year', today(),-3,'S') > date   %put _all_;
         then do;
          file_id = mopen(dir_id,member_name,'i',0);
          if file_id > 0 then do; 
            freadrc = fread(file_id);
            rc = fclose(file_id);
            rc = filename('delete',member_name,,,'filelist');
            rc = fdelete('delete');
         end; %put _all_;
         rc = fclose(file_id);
      end;
      end;
      rc = dclose(dir_id);
   run;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one bug in your code that might be causing unexpected behaviour:

```
month = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.);
day = input(substr(datestring,5,2),best.);
```

I think you meant to type:

```
day = input(substr(datestring,7,2),best.);
```

I wouldn't do this, though - it's quicker to use date informats to do this:

```
date = input(datestring,yymmdd8.);
```

However, I think the bigger problem is with this line:

```
if intnx('year', today(),-3,'S') > date then do; /*Deletion logic follows*/
```

If you have a file that you don't want to delete that isn't in the same format, it's likely that `date` will have a missing value, as it won't have a date in the place where you're looking and the input functions earlier on will return missing values. In SAS, numeric missing values are less than any non-missing numeric value, so this condition will evaluate to true except for files with names in the format that you want to delete that are less than 3 years old.

You can avoid missing values fairly easily by tweaking your code like so:

```
if intnx('year', today(),-3,'S') > date and not(missing(date)) then do;
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful and consider upvoting it - it's how this site works.